# SQL Error Access 2010 VBA Update Command

Tags: sql, vba, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I need help figuring out an error in my SQL statement.  I have been trying several things, but nothing seems to work?
This is the error message I receive

```
Run-time error '3075':

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '([description] = Manufacturing and Delivery Schedule AND [pr_num] = 83)'.
```

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
' ===================================================
' Receives the selected item in the combo box
' ===================================================

' Open the Database connection
Dim data_base As Database
Set data_base = CurrentDb

' Grab description and pr number from the form
Dim desc As string
dim pr_number as long
desc = Combo4.Value
pr_number = Text8.Value

' Build the query
Dim query As String
query = "UPDATE VDR_Table " & _
    "SET [received] = [p1] " & _
    "WHERE ([description] = " & desc & _
    " AND [pr_num] = " & pr_number & ");"

Dim rec_set As DAO.Recordset
Set rec_set = data_base.OpenRecordset(query)

' Build the QueryDef
Set qd = data_base.CreateQueryDef("")
qd.SQL = query

' Execute query
qd.Parameters("p1").Value = true
qd.Execute

' Close nad null record set
rec_set.close
set rec_set = nothing

' Close the connection to the database
data_base.Close

' Prompt the user success
MsgBox "Item has been received"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the description field value you are setting in quotes since it is a string field. It should look like this:

```
' Build the query
Dim query As String
query = "UPDATE VDR_Table " & _
    "SET [received] = [p1] " & _
    "WHERE ([description] = '" & desc & _
    "' AND [pr_num] = " & pr_number & ");"
```

Removed the links below since they don't matter in this case.

<strike>Also, I would recommend using parameters instead of string concatenations to avoid SQL injections. Here's an example of using parameters with VBA - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181734 - and here is some reasoning on why to use parameterized sql - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html.</strike>

Comment: You will have difficulties with DAO, parameters and a long string. SQL Injection is not quite the same in MS Access. I would be inclined to escape any possible single quotes in desc.

Comment: Escaping the quotes sure, but if he uses parameters wouldn't that take care of that issue?

Comment: You cannot use a parameter with DAO and a string longer than 255.

Comment: Putting it in quotes took care of my error message, but I am getting another error.  It is giving me an error in the qd.Execute line.  Says it is expecting 2 parameters?  Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm not too worried about injection attacks.  This is just an inter-office application and doubtful anyone would want to try and get the information that is here.

Comment: The parameter example you show uses ADO, by far the slowest option for MS Access. While SQL injection is a real worry, it is just not the same for the majority of MS Access applications, whereas switching from DAO to the much less viable ADO would be a real problem.

Comment: Yea I'm not as familiar with the best methods for VBA and MS Access, so however you want to get it done is up to you.  As for the parameter error, maybe the execute command requires 2 parameters in it's call?  Like I said, not as familiar with VBA so that's just a longshot guess.